# Arrange seven $0’s$ and seven $1’s$ cyclically

Tags: combinatorics

Arrange seven  $0’s$ and  seven  $1’s$ cyclically so  that  the $14$ strings of $4$  consecutive digits are all the binary strings other than $0101$ and $1010$.

Could you like give an example or some hint to solve my problem.. Thank's

Answer (score 2):

You have to have $100001$ and $011110$ in there somewhere. They could be overlapping, adjacent or separate. Adjacent doesn't work because it would form the excluded strings. Separate requires joining them with one more $0$ and one more $1$ in between, and by symmetry it doesn't matter which one you put where, so that's $10000110111100$. This is indeed a solution of your problem. You could also try the overlapping option.